# Running a JavaScript file under the source origin in the header of an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

Let's say I have a site ***SiteOne.com*** in which I would like to run a JavaScript file originating from ***SiteTwo.com***, but instead of inheriting the origin *http://SiteOne.com:1234* I would like the script to keep its original origin *http://SiteTwo.com:1234*

One way I know this can be done is through the use of an < iframe > like so:

An HTML file, hosted on ***SiteTwo.com*** under /script:

```
<script>console.log(location.origin);</script>
```

On ***SiteOne.com***:

```
<iframe src="http://SiteTwo.com/script" style="visibility:hidden;display:none"></iframe>
```

The console on ***SiteOne.com*** will print:

> http://SiteTwo.com:1234

The problem with this approach is that the < iframe > belongs to the < body > of the HTML file, which causes browsers (or at least Chrome) to render the < iframe > and everything that comes after it as the body of the page.

Are there other ways I could achieve the same, but with a tag which is accepted within the header of an HTML file?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what the script would be doing? Also, do you own both sites?

Comment: @robertodecurnex the script itself would be fetching and storing data from/to localStorage or IndexedDB (or something else able to store data on the client side). My goal would be to share this data across domains, all of which I own, yes. My current implementation uses an iframe that I can communicate with through the [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) functionality. The problem is that I would like to be able to access this data at the beginning of the page load, and not at the start of the < body >.